# I want to know setting interval 7d in kibana3's histogram makes a graph based on what day of the week

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to know setting interval 7d in kibana3's histogram makes a graph based on what day of the week.
In my case, setting based on intervall 7d provides a graph.

> 10/09 ...
>
> 10/16 (10/10 ～10/16)
>
> 10/23 (10/17 ～10/23)
>
> 10/30 (10/24 ～10/30)
>
> 11/06 (10/31 ～11/06)
>
> 11/13 (11/07 ～11/13)

Setting based on interval 1w provides a graph based on Tuesday.

> 10/06 ...
>
> 10/13 (10/07 ～10/13)
>
> 10/20 (10/14 ～10/20)
>
> 10/27 (10/21 ～10/27)
>
> 11/03 (10/28 ～11/03)
>
> 11/10 (11/04 ～11/10)

Are these correct?

If I want to make a graph based on Wednesday, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

setting interval 7d in kibana3's histogram makes a graph based on what day of the week. In my case, setting based on intervall 7d provides a graph